# How do I use pdf.js close PDF?

Tags: pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js as an embedded PDF viewer in a web application I'm building.  I have an iframe that I use as the 'viewer' by setting (via javascript) the SRC attribute to the following:

```
$('#fileViewer-1').find('iframe').attr('src', 'js/pdfjs-1.4.20/web/viewer.html?file%2FMYFOLDER%2FIMAGES%2FPDFdocs%2F' + filename + '#zoom=page-width');
```

so I'm basically just calling this URL as the SRC of my iframe:

```
js/pdfjs-1.4.20/web/viewer.html?file=MYFILENAMEHERE.pdf
```

and now I see memory increasing with each subsequent PDF load (where I change the SRC url attribute to a *new* PDF document).

QUESTION:  how can I call the pdfViewClose() function / method I see on line #6432 of viewer.js?

As I understand it, without calling this, memory in the browser may not be de-allocated.

Currently I'm seeing memory increase steadily and eventually the browser (Firefox) crashes after a number of PDF changes.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here is a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017576/6828657

---

Is this the pdf viewer you're using?

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-can-i-specify-a-different-pdf-in-the-default-viewer

As it says there, can you try to use `PDFViewerApplication.open(file)` to open a new pdf?